# Whois CNAME record not forwarding to heroku custom domain

Tags: heroku

I've added a custom subdomain to my herokuapp as

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

pointing to

```
example.herokuapp.com
```

In my Whois CNAME records, I've added a new record as follows:

```
Zone id.    XXXXXXX


Record Id   XXXXXXXX


Name    subdomain.domain.com


Class   IN


Type    CNAME


Status  Active


Value   example.herokuapp.com


TTL 28800


Creation Date   2015-08-08 19:14:54.753498
```

But this is still not resolving and accessing the url gives me

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

When I check my CLI with heroku domains, it gives me the list of domains I've added to the app.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to subdomain.domain.com. Yours should be subdomain.herokuapp.com